# How to export customised ribbons in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have the following scenario: I have created a few ribbons for several entities in our dev server. Can I now export this ribbons customisations to another server? Or do I have to create them all again?

I have been using CRM 2011 and Ribbon Workbench.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export your ribbons using a solution. Just include the entities where you customized the ribbon and the `Application Ribbons` component if you edited global ribbons.

[image]